# Recover image files accidentally deleted from Google Cloud bucket

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to recover lost files in Google Cloud?

Only deleted this evening by a quirk of fate, I ran a task that should not have been run.

All the data is image data, so before I write some code to stub the lost images with a template image I'd like to know if it is at all possible to recover them?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Allow me a constructive reply, Chez. We get around twenty folks a day attempting to transfer their urgent work onto volunteers, and to do this they use language that attempts to hurry. It is the community view that this is not a decent way to deal with people who are, after all, here in their own free time. "Accurate" begging is still begging. I am not looking to embarrass you - it is just feedback, and all Stack Overflow members are at liberty to offer it. You don't have to reply to me, but if you do, please do so constructively. Best regards to you.

Comment: (FWIW, my first comment is _boilerplate_ - I use it so often it is copy+paste. There's [a fair few of them](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments/master/sites/stackoverflow.com/questions.md)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) provides [Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) which lets you do exactly what you're asking for - be able to recover previous versions of objects (i.e. files) including deleted ones similar to a version control system.

However, you need to turn on Object versioning for a GCS bucket before you can go over the different versions of objects within the bucket. Without that it is not possible to recover any files deleted from your GCS bucket.

> ### [How Object Versioning works](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning#_How)
>
> Cloud Storage allows you to enable Object Versioning at the bucket
> level. Once enabled, a history of modifications (overwrite / delete)
> of objects is kept for all objects in the bucket. You can list
> archived versions of an object, restore an object to an older state,
> or permanently delete a version, as needed.
>
> All objects have generation numbers that allow you to perform safe
> read-modify-write updates and conditional operations on them. Note
> that there is no guarantee of ordering between generations.
>
> When an object is overwritten or deleted in a bucket which has
> versioning enabled, a copy of the object is automatically saved with
> generation properties that identify it. You can turn versioning on or
> off for a bucket at any time. Turning versioning off leaves existing
> object versions in place, and simply causes the bucket to stop
> accumulating new object versions. In this case, if you upload to an
> existing object, the current version is overwritten instead of
> creating a new version.